# How do I get the content type name using code?

Tags: nodes, 8

I'm working on Drupal 8 and I want to get content type machine name and label. Here is my code:

```
$cont_type = node_type_get_types();
foreach ($cont_type as $key => $value) {
  $label = $value->name;
  $machine_name = $key;
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Cannot access protected property `Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::$name`

Hoe can I get the content type name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a property, there is [`ConfigEntityBase::get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityBase.php/function/ConfigEntityBase%3A%3Aget/8). Since `ConfigEntityBase` is a base class for `NodeType`, you can always use `$value->get('name')` to get the value of the *name* property.

Answer (score 0):

name is the label of the node type entity, so you can get that with `$node_type->label()`. That works for any entity type, if what you want is specified as the label key in the entity type annotation.

Answer (score -1):

To get names of content type you can use below function

```
node_type_get_names();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$cont_type = node_type_get_types();
foreach ($cont_type as $key => $value) {
  $label = $value->get('name');
  $machine_name = $key;
}
```