# If Content Type Equals, then

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm trying to get run some code if the content type of the current page is equal to `events`. I am using Drupal 8.

However, I'm unable to write the if statement.

I've tried:

```
if ($node->type == 'events'){...}
if (Node::getType == 'events'){...}
```

I also saw [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163643), but I have no idea how to apply it.

Full code:

```
// Add og:event:start_date meta tag

function MY_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'events'){
    $time = [
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => [
        'http-equiv' => 'og:event:start_date',
        'content' =>  $node->field_next_time->value,
      ],
    ];

    $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$time, 'og:event:start_date'];  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pull the node object out of the variables array.

`$node = $variables['node'];`

In certain preprocess functions this may not be available, so you can try the request service:

`$node = \Drupal::request()->get('node');`

The object must be of type `Node`. Therefore:

`$node->getType() == 'events'`

As Berdir mentioned, you should check and ensure that `$node` is a valid `Node` object to see if it is an instance of `NodeInterface` before operating on it. This will prevent fatal errors in the event that `$variables['node']` is actually a node and not some ad-hoc variable created in code from which you can't call methods on:

#### Example 1 (using `$variables` array):

```
if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node'] instanceof NodeInterface) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $title = $node->getTitle();
  $type = $node->getType();
  // more code...
}
```

#### Example 2 (using the request):

```
$node = \Drupal::request()->get('node');

if (isset($node) && $node instanceof NodeInterface) {
  $title = $node->getTitle();
  $type = $node->getType();
  // more code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object`. Also, `var_dump($node);` returns `NULL`

Comment: Because node has not been assigned. See updated answer.

Comment: you should always include an $node instanceof NodeInterface check, when getting it from the request as not all pages have a node. As well as an isset() on $variables when using that.

Comment: Good info, updated.